# MySQL Return All record even is active or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get some record from my table where `is_active = 1`, but my query return the result even record's `is_active = 0`. I am sure this is my query mistake.

This is my **Query**

```
SELECT `id`, `postal_code`, is_archived, is_active, `email`, `company`, `partner`, `telephone`, `description`
FROM `firm`
WHERE ('is_archived' =0 AND 'is_active' = 1)
AND `email` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `company` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `partner` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `telephone` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Add some expected output.

Comment: ok let me add that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because you are comparing a `string` with `numeric` value here,

```
WHERE ('is_archived' =0 AND 'is_active' = 1)
```

It should be like,

```
WHERE (`is_archived` = 0 AND `is_active` = 1)
```

Column names should not be quoted with `'`.
So the full Query should be,

```
SELECT `id`, `postal_code`, is_archived, is_active, `email`, `company`, `partner`, `telephone`, `description`
FROM `firm`
WHERE (`is_archived` =0 AND `is_active` = 1)
AND (`email` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `company` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `partner` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `telephone` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!')
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: why this happening something this small mistake waste whole day.??

Comment: It's a regular practice for DB Devs to find this kinda small mistake.

Comment: also upvote this answer to help others with the same mistake in future.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `OR` logical conditions together within parenthesis to make the precedence prior than `AND`:

```
SELECT 
`id`, `postal_code`, is_archived, is_active, `email`, `company`, `partner`, `telephone`, `description`
FROM `firm`
WHERE 
is_archived =0 
AND is_active = 1
AND 
(`email` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `company` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `partner` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `telephone` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!')
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Wait and don't put column names within single quote:
`'is_archived'` AND `'is_active'`

Comment: after adding bracket there is not result returned.

Comment: Can you also add some resultset to the ques?

Comment: Wait and don't put column names within single quote

Answer (score 0):

### Try this it should work for you

```
SELECT `id`, `postal_code`, is_archived, is_active, `email`, `company`,`partner`, `telephone`, `description` 
FROM `firm` WHERE `is_archived` =0 AND `is_active` = 1 AND 
(`email` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `company` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR `partner` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR `telephone` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!')
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

> don't put column names within
>   single quote

- 'is_archived' AND 'is_active'

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT `id`, `postal_code`, is_archived, is_active, `email`, `company`, `partner`, `telephone`, `description`
FROM `firm`
WHERE 'is_archived' = 0 AND 'is_active' = 1
AND (`email` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `company` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `partner` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `telephone` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!')
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably meant this:

```
SELECT `id`, `postal_code`, is_archived, is_active, `email`, `company`, 
`partner`, `telephone`, `description`
FROM `firm`
WHERE (`is_archived` =0 AND `is_active` = 1)
AND (`email` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `company` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `partner` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `telephone` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!')
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You had missing parenthese. See following article on  [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql)
And you had incorrectly quoted columns is_archived and is_active as Nirav correctly pointed out.

Comment: provide a `MySQL` link not `MSSQL`, as question is tagged `MySQL`.

Comment: I did it intentionally. This is general stuff and documentation on MSDN is much more readable. Here is MySQL link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html